# jQuery remove top div parent if?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im trying to hide a container `div` if it has no visible children.

Following is my current code:

```
<ul class="category-topics">
  <li class="item-i">I</li>
  <li class="item-ii">II
    <ul class="level-2">
      <li class="item-a">A</li>
      <li class="item-b">B
        <ul class="level-3">
          <li class="item-1">1</li>
          <li class="item-2">2</li>
          <li class="item-3">3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-c">C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item-iii">III</li>
</ul> 

<ul class="category-topics">
  <li class="item-i">I</li>
  <li class="item-ii">II
    <ul class="level-2">
      <li class="item-a">A</li>
      <li class="item-b">B
        <ul class="level-3">
          <li class="item-1">1</li>
          <li class="item-2">2</li>
          <li class="item-3">3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-c">C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item-iii">III</li>
</ul>
```

if at any time a category-topic has all of the following classes hidden.

```
<li class="item-1">1</li>
<li class="item-2">2</li>
<li class="item-3">3</li>
```

Then hide the category that has no visible children and only that one.

How can this be achieved?

What i am doing now:

```
$('.category-topics').each(function(i, obj) {
    if($('.level-3').children(':visible').length == 0) {
   console.log('All children is empty');
}
});
```

Comment: Just edited my post - j08691

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the underlying element with class `.level3` inside the each loop by using `.find()` on the current element.

```
 $('.category-topics').each(function(i, obj) {
       if($(this).find('.level-3').children(':visible').length == 0) {
         alert('All children is empty');
         $(this).find('.level-3').hide();  // hides the ul element
    }
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/6x80vabm/14/